# AJAX POST throws a 415 Unsupported Media Type Error with message 'Request must have "Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json"'

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, flask

I have an application that on click of a button, it makes an ajax post request to a flask backend(flask restless). As mentioned, I get an error with the message "Request must have 'Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json'", even though I have that same statement as part of my header.
Pointer, the post request gets posted successfully on the postman.

```
$(function() {
  $('#add_details').on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/user',
      data: {
        "data": {
          "type": "user",
          "attributes": {
            "first_name": "first",
            "last_name": "second",
            "email_address": "user43@gmal.acbde",
            "phone_number": "4202024234",
            "gender": "FEMALE"

          }
        }
      },
      headers: {
        Accepts: 'application/vnd.api+json',
        ContentType: 'application/vnd.api+json',
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(newUser) {
        console.log('success', newUser)
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error encounted while adding user');
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Q: Shouldn't the header be `Content-Type:` (with a "-")?

Comment: I've tried that but when I do so, javascript throws a "Syntax error: missing : after property id", it doesn't seem to understand 'Content-Type'

Comment: @paulsm4 That is actually correct in javascript. If you set it as a string then you have to do `"content-type"`.

Comment: I've tried "content-type", but that now gives me a "404 - Bad Request error"

Answer (score 0):

```
headers: {
    Accepts: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    ContentType: 'application/vnd.api+json',
  },
```

I noticed an extra comma at the end of ContentType. Have you tired removing that?

Comment: yeah, I've tried removing it, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem either

Comment: Might be helpful to see the full error message, plus a screenshot of your Postman headers.